# My else part of add to cart functionality is also putting the new quantity in the cartItems array rather than just increasing quantity of Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

cartItems is a state array that contains the items that user adds and the logic that I have used is that if the item already exists in the cart then increase its quantity else put the quantity to 1.

```
const [cartItems,setCartItems]=useState([])
  
  const handleAddItem=(item)=>{
     if(!cartItems.find(product=>product.id===item.id)){
        setCartItems([...cartItems,{...item,quantity:1}])
     }
     else{
       setCartItems([...cartItems,
        cartItems[cartItems.findIndex(product=>product.id===item.id)]
        .quantity++])
     }
  }
```

After adding a item 5 times to  the cart I'm getting following result but I only want object inside the array and not other elements.

```
 [Object, 1, 2, 3, 4]
0: Object
id: 1
name: "Sunday"
price: 100
quantity: 5
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
```

Comment: I believe you should have separate state for maitaining total quantity for your inventory

Comment: I am using the reduce method to get the total quantity and total amount.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the code below can be used in else condition

```
else{
cartItems[cartItems.findIndex(product=>product.id===item.id)].quantity++
      setCartItems([...cartItems])
}
```